# Problem installing Bumblebee on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, bumblebee

I have problems with bumblebee installation on Ubuntu 12.04,
when I use this code to install it, I got this message in terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package bumblebee is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'bumblebee' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee-nvidia
```

Last 2 lines are problematic.

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest checking your Software Sources. Delete anything related to Bumblebee and follow these steps:

### Installing Bumblebee under Ubuntu 12.04

Open up a terminal and enter these commands:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable && sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install bumblebee`

See also [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Comment: Thansk it worked and installation went without error. But what now? My Nvidia card will work or I need to do some something more?

Comment: Nevermind, found this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Usage     Thanks for help! :)

Comment: @funkeh: I've edited your answer, adding yourself to the `bumblebee` group manually is not necessary anymore as it's done during installation. All those 32-bit dependencies are also automatically installed (can be overridden though with `--no-install-recommends`). See wiki as linked by tom.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Fair enough. Sounds good.